# При создании потока появляется ошибка "Кадр не находится в модуле"

Tags: c, winapi

только начинаю учить процессы и потоки, создал процесс который должен выполнять функцию вычисления факториала, однако при попытке запуска появляется ошибка "Кадр не находится в модуле". Подскажите с чем это может быть связано и как это исправить.
Код:

```
int gn = 0;
scanf_s("%d", &gn);
HANDLE h = CreateThread(
    NULL,
    0,
    factorial(gn),
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL
);
CloseHandle(h);
return 0;
```

Comment: А `factorial(gn)` просто считает факториал? Тогда Вы неверно все поняли. Вы должны передать указатель на функцию. А параметр - отдельно

Comment: Большое спасибо за Ваш ответ, исправил код, но к сожалению ошибка все та же
int (*fact)(int) = factorial;
    int gn = 0;
    HANDLE h = CreateThread(
        NULL,
        0,
        fact(gn),
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL
    );
    CloseHandle(h);
    return 0;
Вероятнее всего я неверно передаю параметр?

Comment: Вы просто поменяли имя функции. Получается, что CreateThread вычисляет значение функции факториала и это значение передает как адрес функции, которую будет запускать CreateThread. Очевидно, что это разломается. Читайте внимательнее документацию.

Comment: Понял, ошибку удалось исправить, но никак не могу понять как тогда нужно передавать параметр. Это делается при помощи ThreadFunc или как-то иначе?

Comment: lpParameter же использовать

Comment: Казалось, что разобрался с передачей параметра путем добавления ссылки, ошибка исчезла, но, видимо я просто конвертирую в целочисленный в ссылку, а не передаю параметр: (int *)gn, к тому же после этого не могу разобраться как получить возвращаемое значение функции